# Force file sync for CMake build in WSL environment

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022, wsl-2

### Background

I have inherited a firmware project for an STM32 MCU which already defines a build process using docker that generates the .bin and .elf binaries. I'm trying to set up my development environment with Visual Studio 2022 and Cmake so that I can trigger a build in a WSL distro and sync the generated .elf and .bin files back to my windows host to be used with a gdb server. I have written the following (simplified) CMakeLists.txt file which successfully runs the existing docker images to build the project:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("firmware_cmake")

include(ExternalProject)

set(DOCKERFILE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})


ExternalProject_Add(
    build_image
    PREFIX build_image
    SOURCE_DIR ${DOCKERFILE_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND rm -rf ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/autogen ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/build ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/.tup
    BUILD_COMMAND docker build -t build-img .
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    ALWAYS TRUE
)

ExternalProject_Add(
    build_cont
    DEPENDS build_image
    PREFIX build_cont
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND docker rm build-cont
    BUILD_COMMAND docker run -i -v ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}:/FW --name build-cont build-img
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    ALWAYS TRUE
)

add_custom_target(copy-runtime-files ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/build/Firmware.bin
            ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Firmware.bin
    DEPENDS build_cont)
```

### Problem

The firmware files that are being generated are not being synced back to my windows host computer when I execute a build or re-build. If I log into my WSL distro, I can see that the files are being built and exist at `~/.vs/firmware_cmake/out/build/linux-debug/`, but they aren't being synced to `%path-to-my-project%\out\Ubuntu\build\linux-debug`

As a proof of concept, I created a completely new project named `cmake-test` that just has a single hello-world.cpp file with this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("cmake-test")

add_executable (cmake-test-execute "cmake-test.cpp" "cmake-test.h")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT runtime-file.txt
    COMMAND touch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-test/test.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-test/test.txt
            ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.txt
)

add_custom_target(
    copy-runtime-files ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/runtime-file.txt
)
```

Again I can see the `test.txt` file generated in my WSL environment, but it is not synced to my windows host environment; however, I can see `cmake-test-execute` being synced back to my windows host environment.

EDIT: Here is how my CMakePresets.json is configured for this build:

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "linux-debug",
      "displayName": "Linux Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
      "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Linux"
      },
      "vendor": {
        "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/1.0": {
          "sourceDir": "$env{HOME}/.vs/$ms{projectDirName}",
          "copyBuildOutput": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Question

How do I tell CMake to mark other files as output artifacts so that they get included in the files that are marked for syncing back to my windows machine the same way files added with `add_executable()` are?

I acknowledge I'm probably using cmake in a non-standard way, but because of the way this project is set up I can't really change the method that is being used to build the firmware files.

### References

I'm basically following these guides to accomplish what I'm trying to do:

[wsl walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-build-debug-wsl2?view=msvc-170)

[debugging CMake projects with gdb server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/debugging-linux-cmake-projects-with-gdbserver/#launchconfig)

[debugging an embeded ARM device in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/debugging-an-embedded-arm-device-in-visual-studio/)

[ARM gcc cross compilation in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/arm-gcc-cross-compilation-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-json-reference?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-remote-settings-vendor-map. Specifically `copyBuildOutput`

Comment: Yeah, I feel like that should work, but I have copyBuildOutput set to true, and I'm still not seeing anything. See my Edit with the CMakePresets.json

Comment: `and sync` "sync"? Why not just use them as they are?

Comment: @BDeC what about `rsyncCommandArgs`?

Comment: @Osyotr I have tried using the rsyncCommandArgs: ["-t", "-r"] (basically removing the --delete and adding -r for recursive directories) and haven't seen any differences in behavior. It almost seems like cmake is not getting any of the vendor settings

Comment: @KamilCuk partially for ergonomics, and partially for the requirements of the system. I'm developing on a windows pc, so I'd like to be able to edit and debug code in this environment. To connect to the MCU i'm using a J-tag debugger from SEGGER that can create a gdb server that I can hook into. In order to debug I need to reference the .bin and .elf files

Comment: Sidenote: wsl filesystem can be accessed from windows: `\\wsl.localhost\my-dristro-name`

Comment: @Osyotr Thanks for that tip, I will probably just have to use that until I figure out what my issue is

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to figure out how to fix the problem where my custom target files are not syncing, but to kind of hack the solution I ended up creating a dummy executable null.cpp for CMake to build. I then gave it the same name as the output to main .elf file generated by the docker build and then just overwrote the cmake executable with the docker generated file.

This is what my CMakeLists.txt looks like now:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(fw_source ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/build)
set(fw_build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set(fw_project "firmware")

project (${fw_project} C CXX ASM)

set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_C   .elf)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_CXX .elf)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_ASM .elf)

# link the source files so that cmake is aware of them but does not compile.
# The docker container in WSL will invoke tup to build the actual firmware
# Yes I know GLOB is not recommended for use with CMake sources
file(GLOB_RECURSE fw_sources RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} Firmware/**/*.cpp Firmware/**/*.c Firmware/**/*.h Firmware/**/*.hpp)
set_source_files_properties(${fw_sources} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)

add_executable(${fw_project} ${fw_sources})

# Commands to create the docker build environment
add_custom_command(TARGET ${fw_project}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND rm -rf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/autogen ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Firmware/.tup
    COMMAND docker build -t fw-build-img ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Commands to execute the build within the docker build image
add_custom_command(TARGET ${fw_project}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND docker rm fw-build
    COMMAND docker run -i -v ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}:/FW --name fw-build fw-build-img
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
            ${fw_source}
            ${fw_build})

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${fw_sources})
```

This solution at-least copies over the correctly compiled .elf file; however, as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699550/files-not-syncing-in-visual-studio-for-cmake-build-in-wsl-environment/77753972#comment136984191_77699550) by @Osyotr, I still have to navigate to `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\path-to-project` to copy over the .bin for debugging and flashing to device